# Loading Assemblies with MEF fails on some systems without any error message

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, mef

I have a strange issue with a c# application using MEF. I load plugin from a subdirectory of the application with the following code.

```
public class Loader {


    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugin, IMeta>> operations = null;

    public IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugin, IMeta>> Plugins {
        get {
            return this.operations;
        }
    }

    public void Load(string path) {

        try {
            // An aggregate catalog that combines multiple catalogs
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

            // Add all the parts found in all assemblies in
            // the same directory as the executing program
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(path));

            // Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog.
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            // Fill the imports of this object
            container.ComposeParts(this);

            log.Debug("Done loading: " + path);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            log.Fatal(error);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on 90% of my test systems. But on one systems the Loader does not load a plugin. There is no message or exception. Is there a setting that prevents dynamic loading with MEF?

Comment: Where are your MEF parts located? On the system drive? On a file share?

Comment: The app and the plugins are on local drive. The plugins are in the subdirectory "Plugins" of the corresponding executable.